# Sed: Scraping a Range of Numbers

Tags: regex, bash, sed, screen-scraping

Is it possible to specify a range of numbers (1-31) within where I'm matching for a `<strong`> tag? The tag in output appears as: `<strong>21. Infinite Safari Balls</strong>`.

**Edited**

```
#!/bin/bash

wget -q -O - 'goo.gl/vfYA94' | \
  sed -En '/<strong>([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/,/<\/blockquote>/p' | \
  sed -e :a -e 's/<[^>]*>//g;/</N;//ba'
```

Comment: Not at all clear what you're asking.  What do you want to extract from the input?  The list of items?  The numbers?

Comment: Right now I've extracted everything within the strong tag. I want to filter out the input by specifying a range of numbers after that tag to capture specific cheat codes like so: ```sed -n /<strong>[1-31]/,/</blockquote\>p/``` @MarkReed

Comment: Why does your example input end with a `</strong>` tag but your regular expression ends with a `</blockquote>` tag?

Comment: I target the page at the start of the strong tag and then end where a closing blockquote is because that's where the end of a cheat ends.

Comment: You may want to look into [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html), which is sort of like `sed` for HTML/XML.  It can extract what I think you want from that file with something like this: `xidel http://goo.gl/vfYA94 --extract '//strong[text()>="1" and text() <"32"]/(.|../following-sibling::blockquote[1])'`

Comment: Nice, I'll edit with what I've come up with. It still doesn't solve the extra white space it from removing the html tags. Tell me what you think @MarkReed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, you want to print out the block of lines where the first line has the text `<strong>NN.` where NN is a number between 1 and 31 and stopping with the next line that contains a `</blockquote>`.  `sed` does not have a good understanding of numbers but you can achieve the effect that you want with regular expressions:

```
wget -q -O - 'goo.gl/vfYA94' | sed -En '/<strong>([1-9]|[12][0-9]|30|31)\./,/<\/blockquote\>/p'
```

To reduce the number of backslashes in the regular expression, I used the `-E` option for extended regexes.  The `-E` option is recognized on both Mac OSX and on GNU/Linux although the GNU version of `sed` only documents the use of `-r` for this purpose.

Comment: I see. I came up with the expression: ```([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])```

Comment: -E really does the trick. I had a tough time figuring out how to include a pattern mainly because I'm accustomed to scraping with JS and I'm always thinking in terms of selectors. I like this approach though because it's light weight. Thanks John!